# Como organizar um Array por ordem de Hora?

Tags: c#

Tenho duas listas com formato de `TimeSpan` e outra com formato de `String`. Preciso organizar essas duas listas para crescente e decrescente.

```
        List<string> horaString = new List<string>() 
        { 
          "01:04:00",
          "04:04:00",
          "02:02:10",
          "03:05:00",
          "10:07:00",
          "22:20:00"
        };

        List<TimeSpan> horaTimespan = new List<TimeSpan>() 
        { 
          new TimeSpan(5, 30, 1),
          new TimeSpan(2, 15, 5), 
          new TimeSpan(7, 32, 1),
          new TimeSpan(8, 15, 5), 
          new TimeSpan(1, 23, 1),
          new TimeSpan(3, 15, 5) 
        };
```

Comment: Procure por Split String no Google (para dividir a string em array de string, separando por ":"(dois-pontos)), depois transforme as 3 string e um único valor inteiro (valor = hora*3600 + minuto*60 + segundos), e ordene por ele (procure pelo algoritmo QuickSort)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você pode usar o método `OrderBy` e `OrderByDescending`.

```
        List<string> horaString = new List<string>()
        {
          "01:04:00",
          "04:04:00",
          "02:02:10",
          "03:05:00",
          "10:07:00",
          "22:20:00"
        };


        List<TimeSpan> horaTimespan = new List<TimeSpan>()
        {
          new TimeSpan(5, 30, 1),
          new TimeSpan(2, 15, 5),
          new TimeSpan(7, 32, 1),
          new TimeSpan(8, 15, 5),
          new TimeSpan(1, 23, 1),
          new TimeSpan(3, 15, 5)
        };

        horaString = horaString.OrderBy(p => p).ToList();
        horaTimespan = horaTimespan.OrderBy(p => p.Hours).ToList();

        Console.WriteLine("String crescente");
        horaString.ForEach(p => Console.WriteLine(p));

        Console.WriteLine("Time Span crescente");
        horaTimespan.ForEach(p => Console.WriteLine(p));

        horaString = horaString.OrderByDescending(p => p).ToList();
        horaTimespan = horaTimespan.OrderByDescending(p => p.Hours).ToList();

        Console.WriteLine("String decrescente");
        horaString.ForEach(p => Console.WriteLine(p));

        Console.WriteLine("Time Span decrescente");
        horaTimespan.ForEach(p => Console.WriteLine(p));
```

Veja funcionando no [.Net Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/8wa1zD)

Comment: só não precisa da conversão pra  TimeSpan, se fosse data sim,

Comment: Está certo, vou ajustar

Answer (score 1):

Procure por Split String em C# (para dividir a string em array de string, separando por ":"(dois-pontos)), depois transforme as 3 string em um único valor inteiro (criando uma lista de inteiros)

```
hora = array[0];
minuto = array[1];
segundos = array[2];
valor = hora*3600 + minuto*60 + segundos
```

, e ordene por ele usando o exemplo

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3738639/sorting-a-listint.

Depois retorne o inteiro para o valor original

```
hora = valor/3600;
valor -= hora*3600;
minuto = valor/60;
valor -= minuto*60;
segundos = valor;
```